# Need help finding a solution to achieve word reporting under Android (actually using docx4j)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-emulator, docx4j

I'm an engineering student (end of 3rd year) doing an internship where I have to simplify a procedure for creating word reports (.docx). I decided to develop an Android application so the work can be done from the phones and tablets.

I have achieved to create a Java program under Eclipse, which is fully working, using docx4j.

I am completely new to Android Studio (or the Eclipse plugin, I've got both) and the fact of creating .docx through Android isn't something common.
The program is divided into a few steps, including the import of a .docx template, its analysing then its filling (through MergeFields), and its saving. Those steps are failing.

This is the method used to import a template :

```
private WordprocessingMLPackage getTemplate(String name) throws Docx4JException, FileNotFoundException {
    WordprocessingMLPackage template = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new FileInputStream(new File(name)));
    return template;
}
```

The method used to replace the MergeFields is quite long, but my main problem is that JAXBElements aren't managed in Android Studio.

```
    private static List<Object> getAllElementFromObject(Object obj,
                                                    Class<?> toSearch) {
    List<Object> result = new ArrayList<Object>();
    if (obj instanceof JAXBElement)
        obj = ((JAXBElement<?>) obj).getValue(); 
        //end of code here
        }
```

And finally this is the method used to save the finished report :

```
private void writeDocxToStream(WordprocessingMLPackage template,
                               String target) throws IOException, Docx4JException {
    File f = new File(target);
    template.save(f);
}
```

After trying quite everything I could possibly do (with my newbie level ^_^), I am sure that these three methods are failing, but the only one for which I know the reason is the second one, with the JAXBElements. For the first and last methods, I really don't know what to look for.

The AVD app doesn't crash but no file is generated on my desktop (even if I execute without the replacing method).
I have these messages returned in the logcat :

```
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Stone Edge\Desktop\VGP Pelle.docx: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:456)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.stoneedge.vgp01.Tracto.getTemplate(Tracto.java:123)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.stoneedge.vgp01.Tracto.access$000(Tracto.java:25)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at com.example.stoneedge.vgp01.Tracto$1.onClick(Tracto.java:44)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
07-21 14:34:18.955    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:442)
07-21 14:34:18.956    2326-2326/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 W/System.err﹕ ... 14 more
07-21 14:34:19.008    2326-2338/com.example.stoneedge.vgp01 I/art﹕ Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 1090(56KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 39% free, 2MB/3MB, paused 5.574ms total 67.675ms
```

I know there is a pathing error but I verified the path and checked on the forums and I can't find how I could make it work. I have thought about importing and generating the .docx directly on a device, using the device's path, but I don't have an Android device and so didn't look into how to access to these paths.

If any of you could help, that would be great. If you need any more information or tests etc, I'll be on the forum a few times a day to check the answers.

In advance, thank you.

**EDIT**

I think I have abandoned the idea to go through Android for this project, I'm getting errors filled with "�������" on over a thousand lines in the logcat, I can't even look for what the error is with this... I'll try to find a way to make the .jar app to run on android.

Answer (score 0):

> W/System.err﹕ java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Stone
>   Edge\Desktop\VGP Pelle.docx:

Android does not have the same filesystem and structure as windows. You will want to check out how to [save data into files in android](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html).

Comment: Thing is I managed to finally understand this, redid my code through Assets, but then I get these full "�������" lines of error which don't tell me anything, so I think I'll find another solution to get my thing working (so not with Android Studio). Thanks whatsoever, I checked your link and it helped me to understand what was my first mistake :)